# 13.04 login: lagging after password entry for several seconds

Tags: unity, login

When I login to my Ubuntu 13.04 beta2 (std Unity) session, after I enter the password, there is a deferral of some seconds which is not there on my 12.04. LTS partition.

Can this be related to the dmesg output:

```
[   37.101723] systemd-logind[2350]: New seat seat0.
[   37.101785] systemd-logind[2350]: Failed to save seat data for seat0: No such file or directory
```

and if so, what does it mean? I tried to google that lines but could not find any helpful references.

Using `aptitude` gave me the following information:

```
aptitude search systemd
p libpam-systemd - system and service manager - PAM module 
p libpam-systemd:i386 - system and service manager - PAM module 
p libsystemd-daemon-dev - systemd utility library - development files 
p libsystemd-daemon-dev:i386 - systemd utility library - development files 
i libsystemd-daemon0 - systemd utility library 
p libsystemd-daemon0:i386 - systemd utility library
p libsystemd-id128-0 - systemd 128 bit ID utility library 
p libsystemd-id128-0:i386 - systemd 128 bit ID utility library 
p libsystemd-id128-dev - systemd 128 bit ID utility library - development 
p libsystemd-id128-dev:i386 - systemd 128 bit ID utility library - development 
p libsystemd-journal-dev - systemd journal utility library - development files
p libsystemd-journal0 - systemd journal utility library 
p libsystemd-journal0:i386 - systemd journal utility library 
p libsystemd-login-dev - systemd login utility library - development file 
p libsystemd-login-dev:i386 - systemd login utility library - development file 
p libsystemd-login0 - systemd login utility library 
p libsystemd-login0:i386 - systemd login utility library 
p live-config-systemd - Live System Configuration Scripts (systemd backend) 
p python-systemd - python bindings for the systemd journal 
p python-systemd:i386 - python bindings for the systemd journal 
i systemd-services - systemd runtime services 
p systemd-services:i386 - systemd runtime services 
i systemd-shim - shim for systemd 
p systemd-shim:i386 - shim for systemd
```

Comment: Thx for the hint, I am not sure about reporting a bug in this case. What do more experienced users say? Is it worth a bug report?

Comment: @GiantMolecularKlaus How do you expect developers to fix software is you don't tell them it's broken?

Comment: I do not consideer "broken software" as a strictly binary state. However I interpreted your question as rhetorical and reported a bug.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I removed the `libsystemd-login0` package and rebooted. I know it is a login manager but my system it is still running. Also I find this odd since I thought upstart was the alternative to systemd. Anyway just do the following:

`sudo apt-get remove libsystemd-login0`

It gave me about a 1 to 2 second freeze until I removed the package. If it is going to be needed in the future, I will leave it like that until the time comes when another package needs it. You can find more info about the move to systemd in this [Phoronix article](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTMyMDE).

UPDATE: Comparing your `aptitude` list to mine I would ask you to reinstall/install the following packages:

`sudo aptitude reinstall libsystemd-daemon0 systemd-services systemd-shim`

`sudo aptitude install libsystemd-id128-0 libsystemd-journal0 python-systemd`

This will leave you exactly like I am right now:

```
cyrex@cyrex:~$ aptitude search systemd
p   libpam-systemd                                                                            - system and service manager - PAM module                                                             
p   libpam-systemd:i386                                                                       - system and service manager - PAM module                                                             
p   libsystemd-daemon-dev                                                                     - systemd utility library - development files                                                         
p   libsystemd-daemon-dev:i386                                                                - systemd utility library - development files                                                         
i A libsystemd-daemon0                                                                        - systemd utility library                                                                             
p   libsystemd-daemon0:i386                                                                   - systemd utility library                                                                             
i   libsystemd-id128-0                                                                        - systemd 128 bit ID utility library                                                                  
p   libsystemd-id128-0:i386                                                                   - systemd 128 bit ID utility library                                                                  
p   libsystemd-id128-dev                                                                      - systemd 128 bit ID utility library - development files                                              
p   libsystemd-id128-dev:i386                                                                 - systemd 128 bit ID utility library - development files                                              
p   libsystemd-journal-dev                                                                    - systemd journal utility library - development files                                                 
p   libsystemd-journal-dev:i386                                                               - systemd journal utility library - development files                                                 
i   libsystemd-journal0                                                                       - systemd journal utility library                                                                     
p   libsystemd-journal0:i386                                                                  - systemd journal utility library                                                                     
p   libsystemd-login-dev                                                                      - systemd login utility library - development files                                                   
p   libsystemd-login-dev:i386                                                                 - systemd login utility library - development files                                                   
c   libsystemd-login0                                                                         - systemd login utility library                                                                       
p   libsystemd-login0:i386                                                                    - systemd login utility library                                                                       
p   live-config-systemd                                                                       - Live System Configuration Scripts (systemd backend)                                                 
i   python-systemd                                                                            - python bindings for the systemd journal                                                             
p   python-systemd:i386                                                                       - python bindings for the systemd journal                                                             
i A systemd-services                                                                          - systemd runtime services                                                                            
p   systemd-services:i386                                                                     - systemd runtime services                                                                            
i A systemd-shim                                                                              - shim for systemd                                                                                    
p   systemd-shim:i386                                                                         - shim for systemd
```

Don't mind the **c** state for the login package. I just did not delete the configuration files after removing the package. If the freezing still shows then I created an bug report here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/shadow/+bug/1167642

Comment: Thx for the answer but that library is not installed on my system. I did a beta2 install from scratch and no update btw.

Comment: @GiantMolecularKlaus test to see if it works now.

Comment: I tested your suggested solution (also compared the "aptitude search systemd" output again, only differences are the lacking capital As and the c) but the freeze still remains. I counted the seconds it is 4-5.

Comment: I also marked the bug report duplicate since I had already submitted one due to @Oli's suggestion.