# Kubuntu desktop loads slow after password entry

Tags: boot, kubuntu, login

have looked these questions,

[13.04 login: lagging after password entry for several seconds](https://askubuntu.com/questions/280103/13-04-login-lagging-after-password-entry-for-several-seconds)

[Ubuntu 12.04 desktop loads pretty slow after password entry](https://askubuntu.com/questions/350181/ubuntu-12-04-desktop-loads-pretty-slow-after-password-entry)

All questions address boot problem, the cause is different, hence attaching a log file, If it shows the reason for the delay.

It is a Kubuntu 15.10 system,

The system goes normal till entering the password. After the password is entered, the system gets slower to load the panels and menus. mouse is available even <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd> works, but not menus.

the log,

```
[   19.996858] nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
[   19.996865] Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
[   20.006872] nvidia: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[   20.013589] vgaarb: device changed decodes: PCI:0000:01:00.0,olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=none:owns=io+mem
[   20.013967] [drm] Initialized nvidia-drm 0.0.0 20150116 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 0
[   20.013976] NVRM: loading NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  352.63  Sat Nov  7 21:25:42 PST 2015
[   20.864120] Adding 2949116k swap on /dev/sda6.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:2949116k FS
[   22.152779] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp3s0: link is not ready
[   22.241323] r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: link down
[   22.241335] r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: link down
[   22.241377] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp3s0: link is not ready
[   24.384687] r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: link up
[   24.384704] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp3s0: link becomes ready
[ 2105.330193] PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
[ 2105.607910] PM: Preparing system for sleep (mem)
[ 2106.055124] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
[ 2106.057091] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
[ 2106.058232] PM: Suspending system (mem)
[ 2106.058309] Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
[ 2106.058947] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[ 2106.059053] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[ 2106.061721] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
[ 2106.061771] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Stopping disk
[ 2106.062144] serial 00:03: disabled
[ 2106.062150] serial 00:03: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[ 2106.572053] PM: suspend of devices complete after 513.339 msecs
[ 2106.572634] PM: late suspend of devices complete after 0.578 msecs
```

I see the delay is between

```
[   24.384704] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp3s0: link becomes ready
```

and

```
[ 2105.330193] PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
```

what is the reason? how to fix it? thanks.